# MongoDB - 32 MB document size limit possible now?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I read somewhere a while ago that it would be possible to use 32 MB per document in the future ? Does anybody know when is this going to happen ? Or is it possible already ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the moment the limit size to a document is setted to **16 mb**.

If you need to store biggest data (and not as document) you can use **GridFS** inside MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it doesn't look like it's going to get raised to 32MB. In [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-431?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel#issue-tabs) and [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5923?jql=text%20~%20%2264mb%22) Jira issues you can see that no plans currently exist to raise the limit.